# Shell script to connect to multiple DBs

Tags: shell

I want to create a shell script which will connect to multiple oracle DBs and perform insert statements. I should be able to provide the DB list in a seperate .txt file and call that within my shell script. Maybe use a FOR loop. Please help....

Comment: can you elaborate more and provide with things you have tried ...

Comment: Hi Ajay,
I have an insert query (in a .sql file) which I need to run across 5 different databases (all are hosted on the same server).
The user ID & password are the same for all the 5 DBs.
I need to give the list of DBs in a seperate .txt file so that I dont need to hardcode all the 5 DB names in my shell script.
And the shell script should connect to each of the DBs by reading this .txt file each time and then generate a single consolidated log file.
Using a FOR loop to iterate through each of the 5DBs would be a good option.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as below

```
 while read line 
 do 
     db=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
     ## Your isql line
 done < db_list.txt
```

The above code snipt is written for ksh93 , the db_list.txt will contain the list of db.

Comment: Thanks Ajay. Now another issue while executing the script. Below is my code:

#!/bin/sh

rm *.log

set db_login = username/password@connectstring

sqlplus -s $db_login << eof_disp > log_file_$$.log
while read line 
 do 
     db=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
     @query.sql; 
 done < db_list.txt
eof_disp

But below error is thrown:

SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [logon] [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER}]
where <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_string>] | /

ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Comment: It looks like some parameter is not parsed properly . Try to debug the script